# add object to realm database on class that Inherited FirebaseMessagingService Inherited service (FCM)

Tags: java, android, realm, firebase-cloud-messaging

hello everybody i call below method (SaveMessage )at Public Constructor  (onMessageReceived) [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) for save String in realm but after get notification  when get date from this table its null

```
   public class FireBaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    public static  int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    Handler handler;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    generateNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

    SaveMessage(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //AddList(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    //StartActvity(Integer.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("key_1")));

  }

 public void SaveMessage(final String message){


           Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
               realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                   @Override
                   public void execute(Realm realm) {
                       SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
                       String strTime = simpleDateFormatTime.format(new Date());
                       Number currentIdNum = realm.where(MessagePojo.class).max("id");

                       int nextId;
                       if (currentIdNum == null) {
                           nextId = 1;
                       } else {
                           nextId = currentIdNum.intValue() + 1;
                       }
                       MessagePojo messagePojo =  realm.createObject(MessagePojo.class,nextId);
                       messagePojo.setDate(strTime);
                       messagePojo.setMessage(message);
                       realm.insertOrUpdate(messagePojo); 
                       EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(true);
                       realm.close();
                   }
               });


}
}
```

and i add change listener for this Realm table in one fragment.

thank you for your  reading .

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  What is your comment  communicating with my problem :| ??
and i close realm in last line !

Comment: Because you are closing the background thread Realm before the transaction is committed, instead of closing the Realm that started the async transaction. So your transaction is never committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i solve it with handler and looper  and RealmChangeListener work perefect:

```
public void SaveMessage(final String message){
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("YY/MM/dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
                    String strTime = simpleDateFormatTime.format(new Date());
                    Number currentIdNum = realm.where(MessagePojo.class).max("id");
                    int nextId;
                    if (currentIdNum == null) {
                        nextId = 1;
                    } else {
                        nextId = currentIdNum.intValue() + 1;
                    }
                    MessagePojo messagePojo = realm.createObject(MessagePojo.class,nextId);
                    messagePojo.setDate(strTime);
                    messagePojo.setMessage(message);
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(messagePojo); // using insert AP
                   // EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(true);
                }},
                    new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.e("service", "onSuccess: " );
                            realm.close();
                        }
                    },new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                     @Override
                      public void onError(Throwable error) {
                         Log.e("service", "onError: ",error );
                     }}
            );
           //handler.postDelayed(this, 500);

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
 }
```